# use jquery to call gwt uibinder div element

Tags: jquery, gwt, uibinder

i looking for a manual way of manipulate div element inside uibinder using jquery without using gwtQuery .  is there any example?

the jquery will be inside app.html that has the gwt-entry-point.nocache.js file

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="testapp/testapp.nocache.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>


</body>


<script>

alert( $('.cssclass ul li a img').width() );   //return null ,mean fail

//if i do like below with settimer, success
setTimeout("alert( $('.cssclass ul li a img').width() ) ", 5000) ;  // success, with result 

//if i use jquery.ready() or jquery.load() to call the selector  , all fail



</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about calling those methods *at least* from your `onModuleLoad`? Before that, you can't be sure if GWT finished creating the DOM structure.

PS: Have you looked at [JSNI](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html)? You could then integrate your calls to jQuery methods more smoothly with your GWT code.